# Right-click menu mask persisting on my screen

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-10.10

Somethign very strange has happened on my computer. I'm running the latest install of Ubuntu, and using the latest version of chrome, though this has happened on previous builds of both.

The right-click menu has masked a section of my browser permanently on the screen, which persits no matter which programme I have running.

Here is an image of such:

[image]

As far as I'm aware my graphics are up to date and I don't have any unusual menu options.

Comment: Similar: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55376/white-rectangles-on-screen

Comment: @KeithThompson But I don't think it's related. I found a version with windows but the solution was to update the drivers, and disable Aero, which I can't do....